# How do I test a sum tree?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have 2 lists. One contains `values`, the other contains the `levels` those values hold in a sum tree. (the lists have same length)

For example:

```
[40,20,5,15,10,10] and [0,1,2,2,1,1]
```

Those lists correctly correspond because

```
- 40
- - 20
- - - 5
- - - 15
- - 10
- - 10

(20+10+10) == 40 and (5+15) == 20
```

I need to check if a given list of values and a list of its levels corresponds correctly. So far I have managed to put together this function, but for some reason it's not returning True for correct lists *array* and *numbers*. Input *numbers* here would be `[40,20,5,15,10,10]` and *array* would be `[0,1,2,2,1,1]`

```
def testsum(array, numbers):
    k = len(array)
    target = [0]*k
    subsum = [0]*k
    for x in range(0, k):
        if target[array[x]]!=subsum[array[x]]:
            return False
        target[array[x]]=numbers[x]
        subsum[array[x]]=0
        if array[x]>0:
            subsum[array[x]-1]+=numbers[x]
    for x in range(0, k):
        if(target[x]!=subsum[x]):
            print(x, target[x],subsum[x])
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: You could work your way from the middle of the lists and compare from there, I think it would be a more interesting approach

Comment: How would that work?

Comment: Can't you just create a tree then check the sums while traversing the tree?

Comment: I am trying to do that.

Comment: @user3050748: can you give me please another tree? ie. some ancestor according parents. I already do this tree. So i need another tree for testing

Comment: Another more complicated tree would be [1200,400,300,100,500,250,250,100,100,50,50,200,100,100] and its corresponding array should be [0,1,2,2,1,2,2,1,2,3,3,1,2,2].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this running using [`itertools.takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) to grab the subtree under each level. Toss that into a recursive function and assert that all recursions pass.

I've slightly improved my initial implementation by grabbing a `next_v` and `next_l` and testing early to see if the current node is a parent node and only building `subtree` if there's something to build. That inequality check is much cheaper than iterating through the whole `vs_ls` zip.

```
import itertools

def testtree(values, levels):
    if len(values) == 1:
        # Last element, always true!
        return True
    vs_ls = zip(values, levels)
    test_v, test_l = next(vs_ls)
    next_v, next_l = next(vs_ls)
    if next_l > test_l:
        subtree = [v for v,l in itertools.takewhile(
            lambda v_l: v_l[1] > test_l,
            itertools.chain([(next_v, next_l)], vs_ls))
                   if l == test_l+1]
        if sum(subtree) != test_v and subtree:
            #TODO test if you can remove the "and subtree" check now!
            print("{} != {}".format(subtree, test_v))
            return False
    return testtree(values[1:], levels[1:])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    vs = [40, 20, 15, 5, 10, 10]
    ls = [0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1]
    assert testtree(vs, ls) == True
```

It unfortunately adds a lot of complexity to the code since it pulls out the first value that we need, which necessitates an extra `itertools.chain` call. That's not ideal. Unless you're expecting to get very large lists for `values` and `levels`, it might be worthwhile to do `vs_ls = list(zip(values, levels))` and approach this list-wise rather than iterator-wise. e.g...

```
...
vs_ls = list(zip(values, levels))
test_v, test_l = vs_ls[0]
next_v, next_l = vs_ls[1]
...

    subtree = [v for v,l in itertools.takewhile(
        lambda v_l: v_l[1] > test_l,
        vs_ls[1:]) if l == test_l+1]
```

I still think the fastest way is probably to iterate once with an approach almost like a state machine and grab all the possible subtrees, then check them all individually. Something like:

```
from collections import namedtuple

Tree = namedtuple("Tree", ["level_num", "parent", "children"])
# equivalent to
# # class Tree:
# #     def __init__(self, level_num: int,
# #                        parent: int,
# #                        children: list):
# #         self.level_num = level_num
# #         self.parent = parent
# #         self.children = children

def build_trees(values, levels):
    trees = []  # list of Trees
    pending_trees = []
    vs_ls = zip(values, levels)
    last_v, last_l = next(vs_ls)
    test_l = last_l + 1
    for v, l in zip(values, levels):
        if l > last_l:
            # we've found a new tree
            if l != last_l + 1:
                # What do you do if you get levels like [0, 1, 3]??
                raise ValueError("Improper leveling: {}".format(levels))
            test_l = l

            # Stash the old tree and start a new one.
            pending_trees.append(cur_tree)
            cur_tree = Tree(level_num=last_l, parent=last_v, children=[])

        elif l < test_l:
            # tree is finished

            # Store the finished tree and grab the last one we stashed.
            trees.append(cur_tree)
            try:
                cur_tree = pending_trees.pop()
            except IndexError:
                # No trees pending?? That's weird....
                # I can't think of any case that this should happen, so maybe
                # we should be raising ValueError here, but I'm not sure either
                cur_tree = Tree(level_num=-1, parent=-1, children=[])

        elif l == test_l:
            # This is a child value in our current tree
            cur_tree.children.append(v)
    # Close the pending trees
    trees.extend(pending_trees)
    return trees
```

This should give you a list of `Tree` objects, each of which having the following attributes

```
level_num  := level number of parent (as found in levels)
parent     := number representing the expected sum of the tree
children   := list containing all the children in that level
```

After you do that, you should be able to simply check

```
all([sum(t.children) == t.parent for t in trees])
```

But note that I haven't been able to test this second approach.

Comment: @user3050748 I've added a bit of an improvement on the first approach and what should be a significantly more time efficient approach below (though as yet untested). Let me know if there's anything you don't understand

Comment: If I try to call on your second approach it gives me an error at line `trees.append(cur_tree)` : `local variable 'cur_tree' is referenced before assignment`